# How to get image from camera from fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-camera

In my code I got null on bitmap but Image created successfully and uri is fine but BitmapFactory.decodeFile() return null.

I used fragment below code:

```
public class CameraImage extends Fragment {

private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 1888;
Button button;
private Uri fileUri1,fileUri;
ImageView imageView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_image,
            container, false);

    button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri1 = getOutputMediaFileUri();
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);

        }
    });

    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

           BitmapFactory.Options options;


                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathname);
                    showDialog(bitmap, 1);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    try {
                        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inSampleSize = 2;
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathname, options);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        Log.e("Camera", "" + e2 + "    " + e);
                    }
                }
        }
    }        
}    }

public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile() {

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(MyApplication.getAppContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;

    try {
        mediaFile = File.createTempFile(
                "IMG_" + timeStamp,  
                ".jpg",         
                mediaStorageDir      
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Camera", "" + e);
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                , "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }
    return mediaFile;
}
```

In above code I got null on bitmap in onActivityResult but I got uri from this image is present at that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two types of image we can get via camera:

1) thumbnail image by using below code in onActivityResult:

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                Log.i(TAG, "" + photo + "  /  " + data.getExtras().get("data") + "  / " + data.getData());
                showDialog(photo, 1);
```

2) full quality immage by using below code in onActivityResult:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options;
                options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 2;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathname, options);
                showDialog(bitmap, 1);
```

3) use third party easy and comfortable:

compile 'com.mindorks:paracamera:0.2.2'

[paracamera github](https://github.com/janishar/ParaCamera)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question:

by changing `cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);`

to

```
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri1);
```

Comment: just my mistake

Comment: Do you have another variable named `fileUri` somewhere? It isn't in the code that you posted here.

Comment: When you have numbers on the end of variable names, you are probably doing something wrong. In this case, you need to create more descriptive names. You especially should be careful that each variable is distinct and easily recognizable. You should never have variable names so similar that you easily mix them up.

Comment: In addition, you should prefer local variables over member fields as much as possible. Since `fileUri1` is only used inside `onCreateViewI()` declare it there as you did originally. Most likely `fileUri` is used in a single method as well and not shared between methods, so it should be local, also. This change will help you avoid errors like the one you had before you posted this question.